# How to join same records in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have data like this :

```
| ID | NAME | PRICE    
| 01 | TEST | 5000    
| 01 | TEST | 10000    
| 02 | EAST | 4500    
| 03 | AEST | 5000    
| 03 | AEST | 5000
```

I want to join that same records so the final result is like this :

```
| ID | NAME | PRICE1 | PRICE2    
| 01 | TEST | 5000   | 10000    
| 02 | EAST | 4500   | 0    
| 03 | AEST | 5000   | 5000
```

Comment: Can you also share with us what you have tried so far?

Comment: SQL queries result in before-known columns. Your result shows two price columns. Can there be more? If so, how many? And does it matter, which price to show as price1 and which as price2? Would a string with all prices instead of separate price columnss suffice?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? PostgreSQL? Oracle? MySQL? ...

Comment: How do you determine which prices are "1" and which are "2"?  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.

Comment: thanks for your reply. i try using cursor to get the distinct 'ID' and then loops to insert value as the result but still the result is not what i want.

Comment: btw, this problems happen because my company want to migration from old database to new database. the old one from sybase with those data.

Answer (score 0):

SQL tables represent unordered sets.  Given the information you have provided, there is no way to determine the `price1` and `price2` as you have specified.  So, you might as well use `MIN()` and `MAX()`:

```
select id, name, min(price) as price1, max(price) as price2
from t
group by id, name;
```

If you did have a column that specified the ordering, then you could use `pivot` or conditional aggregation:

```
select id, name,
       max(case when seqnum = 1 then price end) as price1,
       max(case when seqnum = 2 then price end) as price2
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by ??) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by id, name;
```

The `??` is for the column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: thanks for you reply. but how if the price field have the same value with same id?

Answer (score 0):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('Tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL
Drop table #Temp
;With cte(ID,NAME,PRICE)
AS
(
SELECT 01 , 'TEST' , 5000  UNION ALL  
SELECT 01 , 'TEST' , 10000 UNION ALL   
SELECT 02 , 'EAST' , 4500  UNION ALL  
SELECT 03 , 'AEST' , 5000  UNION ALL    
SELECT 03 , 'AEST' , 5000
)
SELECT *, 'Price' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER()Over(PArtition by NAME Order by NAME) AS Varchar(5)) AS PriceCol INTO #Temp FROM cte

DECLARE @Coulmn nvarchar(max),
        @Coulmn2 nvarchar(max),
        @Sql nvarchar(max)

SELECT @Coulmn=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ '['+ PriceCol +']' From #Temp
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
--SELECT @Coulmn

SELECT @Coulmn2=STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ', '+ 'ISNULL(' + PriceCol + ',''0'')' +' AS  ['+PriceCol +']' From #Temp
FOR XML PATH ('')),1,1,'')
--SELECT @Coulmn2

SET @Sql=' SELECT  ID,NAME, '+@Coulmn2+ ' From 
            (
            SELECT * From #Temp 
            )As Src
            PIVOT
            (
            MAX(PRICE) FOR PriceCol IN ('+ @Coulmn +')
            )Pvt
            Order By Pvt.ID 
            '
Print @Sql
Exec(@Sql)
```